# Rational Peano curves

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-curves, irrational-numbers

An rr function (i.e. *rational rational function*) is a quotient

$$ \frac fg\,:\, \Bbb Q\ \to\ \Bbb Q\cup\{\infty\} $$

such that $\ f,g\,\in\,\Bbb Z[X],\ $ where $\ g\ne 0.$

**QUESTION** Do there exist rr functions $\ \phi\ \psi\ $
such that set

$$ \{(\phi(x)\ \ \psi(x))\,:\, x\in\Bbb Q\}\ \subseteq
        \ (\Bbb Q\cup\{\infty\})^2 $$

is dense in a non-empty open subset of
$\ \Bbb Q^2\,?$

I'd guess -- **NO**.

Comment: Of course, I assume the standard topology in $\ \Bbb Q^2\ $ induced by the euclidean topology in $\ \Bbb R^2.$

Comment: Even with $\phi ,\psi$ in $\mathbb{C}(X)$, your map extends to an algebraic map $\mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$, whose image is an algebraic curve, certainly not dense in $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: @abx, not dense even in an open subset of the plane? I guess I'll remove my question (since it's too well known). (?)

Comment: Is $f\ g$ just the product of $f$ and $g$? The space confuses me.

Comment: @Wojowu, $\ (f\,\ g)\ $ is an ordered pair. I type operations explicitly, e.g. $\ f\cdot g\ $ and never as $\ fg\ $ To me $\ sin\ $ is not a product but sinus function (product would be $\ s\cdot i\cdot n$).

Comment: Since the Chinese and Gutenberg, we hardly ever need "," in mathematical formulas; comas are eyesores.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.

Comment: comas may be eyesores, but commas are sights for sore eyes. I'm putting 'em in.

Comment: Remember elimination theory from algebraic geometry. You just use a resultant to eliminate the parameter. See my notes on Concrete Algebra (on github) for explicit algorithm. So the image is an algebraic curve.

Comment: If we put $\cdot$ and $\circ$ in any multiplication and in any composition of linear operators, the result would be quite more heavy but not more clear --- Good notations only make explicit what is needed for clarity (like commas)

Comment: @GerryMyerson "comas [...]. I'm putting 'em in."

Your action is unethical. Shame on you and on everybody who imposes on others. DO NOT IMPOSE is the one and only ethical commandment. Decent people have to follow it or else they are indecent. If people followed "do not impose" commandment we would have a happy and universally prosperous society. ***** Of course, I am right about avoiding commas and having operations explicitly. You guys see a tree here and there but not the forest.

Comment: @PietroMajer, in 1977, I have written about the translation covariant transformations (mathematics which assisted my computer architectures). With multilevel usage of comp. $\ \circ.\ $ hiding composition symbols would be a disaster. However, I've invented notation that eased the pain and aided understanding. The mathematical notation is mostly an evolutionary creature, it begs for a consistent clean version. A minor example: $\ (a,b)\ (a,b]\ldots\ $ could be my $\ (a;b)\ (a;b]\ldots.\ $ As it is now, $\ (a,b)\ $ may stand for an open interval but also for an ordered pair.

Comment: I personally dislike the semicolon in mathematical notations, but, yes, that's a reasonable solution. Another could be the old $]a,b[$  for open intervals etc. Or maybe, in the spirit of the ceiling/floor functions, $\lfloor a,b \rfloor$, and $\lceil a,b \rceil$ for closed intervals, and so on. But the real problem about notations is to reach a general consensus, which seems still to come. Today $(a,b)$ may denote an ordered pair, an open interval, an inner product, and a greater common divisor!

Comment: Actually this notation for intervals that I invented right now is not bad at all

$\lfloor a,b \rfloor$

$\lfloor a,b \rceil$

$\lceil a, b \rfloor$

$\lceil a, b \rceil$

Comment: @PietroMajer, an analogy is fine but exact reproducing of a symbol is wrong. "*Your*" intervals, at first glance look like ceiling and floor which decreases the readability. Just imagine a text on number theory, ouch!

Comment: In case anyone is confused, when OP writes $(\phi(x)\ \ \psi(x))$, he means what most of us would write as $(\phi(x),\psi(x))$.

Comment: @WlodAA I see your point... so, you see, the main problem is really to reach a consensus ;)

Comment: @PietroMajer, "the main problem is really to reach a consensus ;)" ***** Unfortunately. But AoA says, don't vote. Instead -- THINK! It should be the profoundness as opposed to consensus. When 100 professors spoke in an open letter against Einstein's Relativity, Einstein said: if just one of them were right it would be enough.

Comment: @WlodAA I see that you have created the ([tag:peano-curves]) tag. It might be useful to create also [the tag-wiki or at least the tag-excerpt](http://mathoverflow.net/tags/peano-curves/info). It might help other users to use the tag correctly. (This is probably not a problem here, since the tag name seems to be descriptive enough.) Another reason is that the tags used on only one question are [automatically deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-pruning/info) after certain time [unless they have a tag-wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the resultant to eliminate the variable $X$. Since the resultant is computed over the rationals, the resultant is a rational coefficient polynomial in the two variables of the plane, satisfied on the image of the parameterized curve. See my (undergraduate!) lecture notes [Concrete Algebra](https://github.com/Ben-McKay/concrete-algebra/blob/master/algebra.pdf) on github for complete (and elementary) details.

Comment: This sounds good. I'll check your link. (+1 for now). U'r more or less translating parametrization into equation (roughly speaking).